# Why can't I exclude a keyword in google search

Tags: google-search

I am googling for info about ceph and google cloud, but everytime I do the first results are about job seaerches.

So I tried removing jobs from the search with:

```
"google cloud" "remote Ceph" integrations  -"jobs"
```

Even doing that the first results are about jobs.

[image: search results]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `+"google cloud" +"remote Ceph" +"integrations"  -"jobs"`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong.

You used to be able to hard-eliminate a search term by putting a minus sign before it.

Now, the Google search engine does still pay some attention to that, but treats the minus sign as a suggestion.  Basically, Google decided that their search engine is smarter than people who think they want to be excluding some search results.

While the specifics can change over time, the last time I checked, Google was not offering any way to override their search engine's calculations on when it wants to show you information anyway because it determined it may really actually be able to pleasingly outsmart whomever made the request.

Answer (score 0):

It's location-based.

When I configure my VPN to egress in NL or DE and I use the command I put in comment

```
+"google cloud" +"remote Ceph" +"integrations"  -"jobs"
```

the only result I get is the help.zenoss.com -site that's showing first in the search results. But when I point my VPN to US or UK, the "Jobs" -offering appears. So at least at this for now to prevent it from showing is using a VPN with egress point in the Western Europe.

Apparently it's still on Beta so I'd expect even this workaround to disappear in a near future.